# How can I add a checkbox in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms-view-engine

1. I want to know that how to add the checkbox in the mvc3 asp.net C#.
   I'm using Aspx view engine.
2. I have to add mutiple checkboxes and have to save the data of that checkbox which are selected true.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework ? Do you want to save your data in a database ?

Comment: @Francesco Yes i wants to save it in database and i'm using entity framework

Comment: So, do you use "Code First" with "model class" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is an example:*

In your "Model class":

```
public class TennisCourt
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Extérieur ?")]//=Outside in french
    [Column("Outside")]
    public bool Outside { get; set; }
}
```

*In your "View Index"*

```
@model IEnumerable<TennisOnline.Models.TennisCourt>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Gestion des Courts</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
     Id    
    </th>
    <th>
        Outside ?
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Outside)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

*Here is the result:*

[image]